# Code in Java don't send datas correctly, using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, simulator, scheduledexecutorservice

Good afternoon.

I am doing my Final Year Degree and I'm a bit stuck with a small thing. I explain below to see if anyone can help me, because I can't find a solution.

What I'm doing, among other things, it is a Java simulator to simulate oriented students unhealthy habits to obtain good academic. To do this, this simulator what it basically does is to take a random value of a vector (in this case there are two vectors that are two habits to simulate, which should expand with more habits) and then in the corresponding method is set to a **switch** that will value the variable and the time during which the data is sent. Datas are sent to the following URLs:

What happens when values ​​are different are taken, the time of the study or sleep does not print correctly on the screen to perform the second iteration and other clear (the first time it does well), and of course this can lead that the data are not sent by the allotted time. Let me give an example of what I say:

*Pablo Ruiz whose id is 1 study for: **2 minutes**
Value field 1 in ThingSpeak, Studio: 1
Simulated and sent to ThingSpeak

Luisa Aguilar whose id is 2 study for: **9 minutes**
Value field 1 in ThingSpeak, Studio: 1
Simulated and sent to ThingSpeak*

After 1 minute re-send the data automatically is displayed on screen but the following:

*Pablo Ruiz whose id is 1 study for: **9 minutes**
Value field 1 in ThingSpeak, Studio: 1
Simulated and sent to ThingSpeak

Luisa Aguilar whose id is 2 study for: **9 minutes**
Value field 1 in ThingSpeak, Studio: 1
Simulated and sent to ThingSpeak*

What could I do to fix this?

The simulator code is in:

```
package clases;

public class Simulador{

    private final static String THINGSPEAK_API_KEY_61343 = "6I3NISMSLETFUBZT";
    private final static int CHANNEL_ID_61343 = 61343;

    private final static String THINGSPEAK_API_KEY_66194 = "5EWC7RZNH434456Q";
    private final static int CHANNEL_ID_66194 = 66194;

    private static Estudiante estudiante1, estudiante2;

    private static Temporizador temporizador1 = new Temporizador(), temporizador2 = new Temporizador();

    private static Canal thingSpeak_61343, thingSpeak_66194;

    private static int[] minutosEstudio = new int[]{0,2,3,6,9}, minutosDurmiendo = new int[]{0,3,4,5,6,8};
    private static int valorAleatorio;

    private static int tiempoEstudiando1, tiempoEstudiando2, tiempoDurmiendo1, tiempoDurmiendo2;

    private static int tiempoEstudio, tiempoDormir;

    private static int estudio = 0; //Campo 1 en ThingSpeak
    private static int dormir = 0; //Campo 2 en ThingSpeak


    public static void main (String [] args){     

        estudiante1 = new Estudiante("1", "Pablo Ruiz", "UCA");
        thingSpeak_61343 = new Canal(THINGSPEAK_API_KEY_61343, CHANNEL_ID_61343);
        tiempoEstudiando1 = generarValorAleatorio(minutosEstudio);
        tiempoDurmiendo1 = generarValorAleatorio(minutosDurmiendo);
        generarDatosEstudio(thingSpeak_61343, estudiante1, tiempoEstudiando1);
        generarDatosDormir(thingSpeak_61343, estudiante1, tiempoDurmiendo1);

        estudiante2 = new Estudiante("2", "Luisa Aguilar", "UPO");
        thingSpeak_66194 = new Canal(THINGSPEAK_API_KEY_66194, CHANNEL_ID_66194);
        tiempoEstudiando2 = generarValorAleatorio(minutosEstudio);
        tiempoDurmiendo2 = generarValorAleatorio(minutosDurmiendo);
        generarDatosEstudio(thingSpeak_66194, estudiante2, tiempoEstudiando2);
        generarDatosDormir(thingSpeak_66194, estudiante2, tiempoDurmiendo2);

    }


    private static int generarValorAleatorio(int[] minutosHabito) {
        valorAleatorio =  minutosHabito[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * minutosHabito.length)];
        return valorAleatorio;
    }


    private static void generarDatosEstudio(final Canal thingSpeak11, final Estudiante estudiante11, final int tiempoEstudiando) {

        switch (tiempoEstudiando) {
        case 0:
            estudio = 0;
            tiempoEstudio = 10;
            break;

        case 2:
            estudio = 1;
            tiempoEstudio = 2;
            break;

        case 3:
            estudio = 1;
            tiempoEstudio = 3;
            break;

        case 6:
            estudio = 1;
            tiempoEstudio = 6;
            break;

        case 9:
            estudio = 1;
            tiempoEstudio = 9;
            break;  

        default:
            estudio = -1;
            tiempoEstudio = 0;
            break;
        }

        Runnable tareaEstudio = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                 if(tiempoEstudiando == 0){
                        estudio = 0;
                        System.out.println(estudiante11.get_nombre()+ " cuyo id es " +estudiante11.get_id()+ " no estudiar� durante: " +tiempoEstudio+ " minutos");
                    } else{
                        System.out.println(estudiante11.get_nombre()+ " cuyo id es " +estudiante11.get_id()+ " estudiar� durante: " +tiempoEstudio+ " minutos");
                    }

                    System.out.println("Valor campo 1 en ThingSpeak, Estudio : " + estudio);
                    thingSpeak11.setDataField(1, estudio);
                    System.out.println("Simulado y enviado a ThingSpeak");
                    System.out.println("");
                    thingSpeak11.sendData();

            }
        };

        temporizador1.empezarTemporizadorMinutos(tareaEstudio, tiempoEstudio, 0);

    }

 private static void generarDatosDormir(final Canal thingSpeak_21, final Estudiante estudiante21, final int tiempoDurmiendo) {

        switch (tiempoDurmiendo) {
        case 0:
            dormir = 0;
            tiempoDormir = 10;
            break;

        case 3:
            dormir = 1;
            tiempoDormir = 3;
            break;

        case 4:
            dormir = 1;
            tiempoDormir = 4;
            break;

        case 5:
            dormir = 1;
            tiempoDormir = 5;
            break;

        case 6:
            dormir = 1;
            tiempoDormir = 6;
            break;

        case 8:
            dormir = 1;
            tiempoDormir = 8;
            break;

        default:
            estudio = -1;
            tiempoDormir = 0;
            break;
        }

        Runnable tareaDormir = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(tiempoDurmiendo == 0){   
                    dormir = 0;
                    System.out.println(estudiante21.get_nombre()+ " cuyo id es " +estudiante21.get_id()+ " no dormir� durante: "+tiempoDormir+ " minutos");

                } else{
                    dormir = 1;
                    System.out.println(estudiante21.get_nombre()+ " cuyo id es " +estudiante21.get_id()+ " dormir� durante: " +tiempoDormir+ " minutos");
                }

                System.out.println("Valor campo 2 en ThingSpeak, Dormir : " + dormir);
                thingSpeak_21.setDataField(2, dormir);
                System.out.println("Simulado y enviado a ThingSpeak");
                System.out.println("");
                thingSpeak_21.sendData();
            }
        };

        temporizador2.empezarTemporizadorMinutos(tareaDormir, tiempoDormir, 15);

    }
}
```

Here you can see the code I used for the timer:

```
package clases;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Temporizador {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService servicio;
    private final long periodo = 60;

    public Temporizador(){
        servicio = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    public void empezarTemporizadorMinutos(Runnable runnable, int tiempo, int retraso){

        ScheduledFuture<?> resultado = servicio.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, retraso, periodo, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //ejecuta el runnable cada 60 segundos con un retraso inicial de 0 (para que lo haga directamente)

        Runnable cancelar = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                resultado.cancel(true); //Para que cuando finalice el tiempo, no se siga ejecutando la tarea

                if(servicio != null){
                    servicio.shutdown(); //Para que no se quede en espera una vez finalizada la tarea
                }

            }
        };
        servicio.schedule(cancelar, tiempo, TimeUnit.MINUTES); //Se ejecuta la tarea por el tiempo correspondiente en minutos 
    }


}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Post your code here, not offsite. Few will click an external link here.

Comment: Now, the code is pasted. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Does this code execute?

Comment: I execute this code using Eclipse.

Comment: I added a little markup to make consecutive lines display separately. It's always worth double-checking the way the site displays your question, to make sure it's as clear and legible as possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Thanks.